# Python3: If elif else with while loops in a function

Tags: python-3.x, function, if-statement, while-loop

I am quite confused about what is wrong with my code. I am trying to make a math practice program. However, when I choose an operation, no matter what I type in, it will always take me to addition. Can someone please help me solve this problem. My little brother is not very excitedly waiting. :)

```
from random import randint
print("Welcome to Luke's Math Practice")
score = 0

def mathAddition():
    global score
    numberOne = randint(0, 100)
    numberTwo = randint(0, 100)
    answer = input(f"{numberOne} + {numberTwo} = ")
    correctAnswer = numberOne + numberTwo
    if int(answer) == correctAnswer:
        print("Correct!")
        score = score + 1
    elif int(answer) != correctAnswer:
        print("Incorrect!")
        print("The Correct Answer was", correctAnswer)
        print("Your Score Is:", score)
        choiceOperation()
    else:
        print("Sorry That Was an Invalid Answer")

def mathSubtraction():
    global score
    numberOne = randint(0, 100)
    numberTwo = randint(0, 100)
    answer = input(f"{numberOne} - {numberTwo} = ")
    correctAnswer = numberOne - numberTwo
    if int(answer) == correctAnswer:
        print("Correct!")
        score = score + 1
    elif int(answer) != correctAnswer:
        print("Incorrect!")
        print("The Correct Answer was", correctAnswer)
        print("Your Score Is:", score)
        choiceOperation()
    else:
        print("Sorry That Was an Invalid Answer")

def mathMultiplication():
    global score
    numberOne = randint(0, 20)
    numberTwo = randint(0, 20)
    answer = input(f"{numberOne} * {numberTwo} = ")
    correctAnswer = numberOne * numberTwo
    if int(answer) == correctAnswer:
        print("Correct!")
        score = score + 1
    elif int(answer) != correctAnswer:
        print("Incorrect!")
        print("The Correct Answer was", correctAnswer)
        print("Your Score Is:", score)
        choiceOperation()
    else:
        print("Sorry That Was an Invalid Answer")

def mathDivision():
    global score
    numberOne = randint(0, 20)
    numberTwo = randint(0, 20)
    answer = input(f"{numberOne} / {numberTwo} = ")
    correctAnswer = numberOne / numberTwo
    if int(answer) == correctAnswer:
        print("Correct!")
        score = score + 1
    elif int(answer) != correctAnswer:
        print("Incorrect!")
        print("The Correct Answer was", correctAnswer)
        print("Your Score Is:", score)
        choiceOperation()
    else:
        print("Sorry That Was an Invalid Answer")

def choiceOperation():
    operationChoice = input("Would you like to practice adding, subtracting, multiplying, or dividing? ")
    if operationChoice == "add" or "+" or "adding" or "addition":
        while True:
            mathAddition()
    elif operationChoice == "subtract" or "-" or "subtracting" or "subtraction":
        while True:
            mathSubtraction()
    elif operationChoice == "multiply" or "*" or "x" or "multipying" or "multiplication":
        while True:
            mathMultiplication()
    elif operationChoice == "divide" or "/" or "dividing" or "division":
        while True:
            mathDivision()
    else:
        print("Sorry, That Was an Invalid Choice")

choiceOperation()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line

```
if operationChoice == "add" or "+" or "adding" or "addition":
```

is not doing what you think it is doing.
It is checking if `operationChoice == "add"` or if any of `"+" or "adding" or "addition"` evaluate to true. (All non-empty strings evaluate to True)

Either make it

```
if operationChoice in ("add", "+", "adding", "addition"):
```

OR

```
if operationChoice == "add" or operationChoice == "+" or operationChoice == "adding" or operationChoice == "addition":
```

Comment: Thanks! Great Explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the problem, in your choinceOperation funtion. the if statemnts should looks like:

```
if operationChoice in ("add", "+", "adding", "addition"):
```

The reason why your codes always leads to "+" is that:

```
operationChoice == "add" or "+" or "adding" or "addition"
# (operationChoice == "add") or "+" or "adding" or "addition"
# and the first fails, but the "+" will always be True.
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this and refer to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6762959/if-statement-for-strings-in-python).

```
def choiceOperation():
    operationChoice = input("Would you like to practice adding, subtracting, multiplying, or dividing? ")
    if operationChoice in ['add', '+', 'adding', 'addition']:
        mathAddition()
    elif operationChoice in ['subtract', '-', 'subtracting', 'subtraction']:
        mathSubtraction()
    elif operationChoice in ['multiply', '*', 'x', 'multipying', 'multiplication']:
        mathMultiplication()
    elif operationChoice in ['divide', '/', 'dividing', 'division']:
        mathDivision()
    else:
        print("Sorry, That Was an Invalid Choice")
```